# How to skip the first instance in a foreach loop and limit to 8?

Tags: php, foreach, pagination, limit

I was wondering if anyone could give me a hand with this...
Basically I am trying to modernize the news system of my site but I can't seem to limit the amount of posts showing in the foreach loop that is on my blog part of the site. I need to skip the first instance as it is already promoted at the top of the page. I've tried various google searches but im getting results for C++ Perl and python, what is really irritating. I just need a simple PHP solution. I'll pop my code below and see if anyone can help. Thanks for any help in-advance. And please remember to leave your responses as an answer so I can mark them up if they helped ;)

```
<div class="view22 full" style="margin-top:0;">
    <h3>Recent News and Announcements</h3>
    <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { 
?>
        <div class="ah7_ clearfix">
            <p class="date"><?php echo date('F j', $article['article_timestamp']); ?>, <?php echo date('Y', $article['article_timestamp']); ?></p>
            <h3><a href="<?php echo $url.'/newsroom/'.$article['article_id']; ?>"><?php echo $article['article_title']; ?></a></h3>
        </div>
    <?php 
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the structure of $articles array?

Comment: Learn to use functions such as [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) - problems like this don't exist using the right tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the $articles array has keys starting with 0. How about modifying the loop like this:

```
foreach ($articles as $key => $article)
```

and checking if $key is 0 at the beginning?

```
if($key == 0)
   continue;
```

If the array keys are different: Create a new variable $i, set it to 0 and increase the value by 1 in every foreach loop iteration.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($articles as  $article) {
   $i++;
   if($i == 1)
      continue;
   elseif($i > 8)
      break;

   //the other code goes here
}
```

In case it is based on a SQL query, using "limit" might help to reduce load!

Comment: Thanks so much, this has been doing my head in for the past 3 hours lol. Btw your forgot the semicolon at continue ;)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the first instance you can manually unset the item ($articles[0]) after making a copy of it or printing it as a featured news.

To limit the number of post you can use the mysql LIMIT Clause;

Or you can do something like this

```
foreach($articles as $key => $article){
    if($key===0)
        continue;
    if($key===8)
        break;
    echo $article;// or_do_whatever_youwant_with($article);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using break if the 8th item was displayed. Imagine an array with 10k items: It will run through all of them instead of skipping the loop...

Comment: Sure. You're correct Pi_isnt_42. Can you please edit the answer so it would be more helpful?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do:

1. If you $articles is an array of array, having continous indexes, use a `for` loop instead of `foreach` and do something like

   ```
   for ($i = 1; $i < 8 : $i++ ) { 
     // and access it like
      $articles[$i]['some_index'] ...
   }
   ```
2. If it is not then you can use an external counter
   Say

   ```
       $counter = -1; 
       foreach ( $articles as $article) { 
           $counter++;
           if (!$counter) continue;
           if ($counter > 7 ) break;
       ...// your code //
      }
   ```
3. You can change your Mysql query to give you only the desired data, using LIMIT and OFFSET